# CSS wildcard selection

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I use this wildcard in css to select the data containing "," commas.

```
td[data-content*=","]{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Is there a way to make a distinction for the numbers of `","` in the data. I can highlight data containing one comma in yellow. I'd like to highlight data containing two commas in green. Is there a way to do this with CSS? Thanks.

I want to use different colors at the same time according to the number of commas data contains. So the data like (1,2) will be yellow. and the data like (1,2,3) will be green.

Comment: that would be good, but no you cannot (unless there is a magic trick I don't know)

Comment: I don't think you can do that in pure CSS. You might have to pair it with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I'm open for a JS solution if it's not complicated.

Comment: then all you need is a regex to use with JS ;) updated with relevant tags so you attract the concerned users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution:

```js
$('td').each(function() {
  var c = $(this).text();
  if (!c) return;
  var commas = c.split(",").length - 1;
  if (commas === 1) $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  if (commas === 2) $(this).css("background-color", "green");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a,b</td>
      <td>a,b,c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory:

1. grab `td`s
2. read `data-content` attribute and count commas
3. set style

Comment: I couldn't make it work. I use this js script in my page. `$(function(){
 $("td").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr("data-content", $this.text());
  });
});`

Comment: Why are you changing the `data-content` attribute?

Comment: I add the attribute to use with css I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Ok, so you weren't asking about your problem but about your attempt at solving it... in other words, the text containing the commas is between `<td>` and `</td>` originally? I changed the code accordingly.

Comment: yes, it is. data-content is added with JS. I'm sorry, I didn't mention this before.

Comment: Right. Since this solution doesn't use CSS, setting `data-content` is pointless in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chris G.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in pure CSS.
The CSS attribute selectors only allow literal matching and no wildcard/glob/regexp matching

See here for a definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

I have made a VanillaJS solution. In that I count the comma matches in the `data-content` attribute and add a new `data-content-classification` attribute with different values depending on number of matches.

```js
console.clear()

// Start after loading of the document
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // get all the table cells with data-content attribute
  var tdContents = document.querySelectorAll('td[data-content]');
  // loop over those cells
  for (var i = 0; i < tdContents.length; i++) {
    // anonymous function which gets a single table cell element as argument
    ;(function(el) {
      // get the attribute's value
      var dc = el.getAttribute('data-content')
      // react according to the length of the comma matches (with fallback to prevent error)
      switch ((dc.match(/,/g) || []).length) {
        case 0:
          // if no comma found
          el.setAttribute('data-content-classification', 0);
          break;
        case 1:
          // if one comma found
          el.setAttribute('data-content-classification', 1);
          break;
        default: 
          // default, meaning more than one comma
          el.setAttribute('data-content-classification', 2);
      }
     })(tdContents[i]);
  }
})
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
td[data-content-classification="1"] {
  background-color: yellow;
}

td[data-content-classification="2"] {
  background-color: red;
}

td:after,
td:before {
  order: -2;
  content: "data-content: " attr(data-content);
  background-color: goldenrod;
  min-width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


td:after {
  order: -1;
  content: "data-content-classifiction: " attr(data-content-classification) " ";
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-content="1">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-content="1,2">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-content="2,3">Eveniet, sunt reiciendis.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-content="1,2,3">Accusantium, quam impedit.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-content="1,2,3,5">Accusantium, quam impedit.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this answer contains jQuery notation, and so it will require a jQuery library to work.

What you could do is loop through all your `data-content` that has a `,` like you initially wanted with your wildcard selector.

You can then use `$(this).attr()` to get the contents of your custom attribute.

You can then take that string, turn it into an array using `.split()`. After that you count the length of the array. Remember to subtract by 1, because arrays count from 0.

You then check for the condition of commas and set your CSS logic by using the `css()` function.

Example:

```js
function testing() {
    $('[data-content*=","]').each(function() {
        var myAttr=$(this).attr('data-content');
        var myArr=myAttr.split(",");
        var countCommas=myArr.length - 1;
        var yellow=1;
        var green=2;
 if(countCommas == yellow) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
 }
 else if(countCommas == green) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "green");
 }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-content="1,2">
            1,2
 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-content="1,2,3">
            1,2,3
 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            No color
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="testing();">Test</button>
```

You don't need to trigger the function via a button click, I just added that for test purposes, so that you could see the effect.

If you want it to run automatically, all you have to do is put it inside a `document.ready` block.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-content*=","]').each(function() {
        var myAttr=$(this).attr('data-content');
        var myArr=myAttr.split(",");
        var countCommas=myArr.length - 1;
        var yellow=1;
        var green=2;
 if(countCommas == yellow) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
 }
 else if(countCommas == green) {
     $(this).css("background-color", "green");
 }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td data-content="1,2">
            1,2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-content="1,2,3">
            1,2,3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            No color
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should react to the number of commas in the `data-content` aatribute, not if it is `1,2` or `1,2,3`. That you would be able to do in CSS alone. You should react on values as `4,5`, `7,8,9`, or `1,2,3,4` as well.

Comment: My bad @HerrSerker made it so that it works depending on commas instead rather than the literal contents.

Comment: @Martin This is basically an exact duplicate of my earlier answer.

Comment: @ChrisG I simply changed the literal condition of my answer to fit the count of commas instead as per HerrSerker's request. It's not a duplicate of anything. I am also including more info in my answer.

Comment: @Martin Yes, but by fixing your code, it now does the exact same thing my code did as of five minutes ago, posted way earlier than your fix. However it turns out using `data-content` is nonsense in the first place, and your answer is now technically speaking no longer a duplicate (but not an answer to OP's actual problem).

Comment: How is `data-content` nonsense? It's OP's custom attribute. And how is it not an answer? It does what it's supposed to do? *"Is there a way to make a distinction for the numbers of "," in the data. I can highlight data containing one comma in yellow. I'd like to highlight data containing two commas in green. Is there a way to do this with CSS?"*. It was already covered in comments that JS would be needed, and that OP wouldn't mind a JS solutin.

Comment: @Martin You're too slow :) Check the comments below my answer. OP actually has `<td>a,b</td>` and used jQuery to turn that into `<td data-content="a,b">a,b</td>` in order to select it via CSS. Since CSS doesn't allow to state the number of commas and hence JS is required, copying the `<td>` content is not required in the first place. See my answer. OP fell for [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).